# Categories does not show Block editor Wordpress

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, block-editor

I changed my wordpress plugin from the old editor to the new block editor. 
Everything works fine but my categories meta box is gone.

For my plugin I created a custom taxonomy with this code

```
<?php
function create_scooter_tax() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'scooter_type',
        'scooters', 
        array(  
            'label' => __( 'Categorieën' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'scooter' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )   
    );
}
    add_action( 'init', 'create_scooter_tax' );
?>
```

Is there somebody who knows this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue

I forgot the line **'show_in_rest'=> true,** in the register taxonomy code.